# How can I export a dictionary inside a list that's already in a JSON file? | Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file

I want to get the dictionary below inside my data array, couldn't find much on this as most tutorials show you how to chuck variable right into the json, without ordering it into an array or object.

the JSON:

```
#JSON file

{
    "data" : 
    [
      
    
    ]

}
```

the python file I want to export from:

```
import json 

#Python file

your_facebook_info = {'name':'johhny', 'age':213, 'money':'lots'}
```

desired outcome:

```
{
    "data" : 
    [
      your_facebook_info = {
       'name':'johhny', 
       'age':213, 
       'money':'lots'
      }
    
    ]

}
```

Comment: You are doing an `import json` already. Did you check out `json.load()` and `json.dump()`?

Comment: yes, but that just dumps them in, i need them to be put inside the list when they get dumped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You read the file, append the new data, write that databack to the file.

```
import json 

#Python file

your_facebook_info = {'name':'johhny', 'age':213, 'money':'lots'}
with open('text.json','r') as inputfile:
  data = json.load(inputfile)
  data['data'].append(your_facebook_info)

with open("text.json", "w") as outfile: 
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```